# SSIS Process Error when using LF as Row Delimiter

Tags: ssis

Previously the input file that I have was using CRLF as row delimiter, but now it has been changed to LF. As such I'm encountering issues.

I'm trying to modify the SSIS, on the Flat File Connection manager, to set both Header Row Delimiter and Row Delimiter as LF

[image]

[image]

However, I was still encountering issue. When I check on the SSIS runs, it seems that there is still problem with delimiter and as such the next column was keep getting concatenated and caused truncation error.

In the logs, the header row delimiter and row delimiter do not show up, is it normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2 things I can think of for now.

1. either the header row delimiter or row delimiter is still {CR}{LF} and only the other one is {LF}.
2. there might be a column extra or more likely missing, which then in turn puts the EOL character {LF} in the column and then does not see it to start the new line.